# Laravel 5 form request on update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't understand why this doesn't work, i have searched the forums and read the official documentation, obviously I'm making a silly mistake:

```
public function rules()
{
    $customer = Customer::find($this->customers);
    return [
        'data.name'       => 'required|unique:customers,name,1'
    ];
}
```

That is a CustomerUpdateFormRequest that i created, i manually typed the customer id which is 1 in the rule, also with: `'data.name'       => 'required|unique:customers,name,'.$customer->id,`

The problem is that it still doesnt pass the unique validation, i giving me the Customer already exists error even after manually or dynamically type the customer id.

I read this http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update and I 'Believe' that my code is correct, why is not working?

Comment: May I ask why you have `'data.name'` as the key and not just `'name'`?

Comment: Yes! sure, im sending an array named data[], so if i need to get something from it i need to call the Key with a dot, example: 'data.name', 'data.country' etc.

Comment: Ah alright, so it's `$data = ['data' => ['name' => ...]]`?

Answer (score 1):

The code above is working just fine, no syntax errors or logic, the problem was in the database, there was another customer with the same data inserted i guess before the validation form was created.

I dont know if i should delete this question or leave it here, anyway the code its fine if u have any problems like mine PLEASE CHECK YOUR DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function rules()
{

    $customer= $this->route('customer'); //$this->('route-name')

    return [
        'data.name'       => 'required|unique:customers,name,' . $customer->id
    ];
}
```